# how can i resolve validation error in node js

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, validation

I have to do a validation where for an idteam you cannot create more than 5 players. I use node js with express and mlab (mongo db) with heroku.

```
    playerModel.count({ idteam: player.idteam }, function (err, count) {
    console.log('el equipo tiene %d jugadores', count);
    if (count > 5){
        throw 'Equipo completo'
    }
  });
```

I make a count on a certain idteam and when I do the validation on the data saved in count it gives me the following error when the condition is met

```
Error [ERR_UNHANDLED_ERROR]: Unhandled error. ('Equipo completo')
at Function.emit (events.js:187:17)
at C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\API JUGADORES\node_modules\mongoose\lib\model.js:4640:13
at C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\API JUGADORES\node_modules\mongoose\lib\utils.js:581:16
at result (C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\API JUGADORES\node_modules\mongodb\lib\operations\execute_operation.js:75:17)
at session.endSession (C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\API JUGADORES\node_modules\mongodb\lib\operations\execute_operation.js:64:11)
at ClientSession.endSession (C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\API JUGADORES\node_modules\mongodb\lib\core\sessions.js:135:41)
at executeCallback (C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\API JUGADORES\node_modules\mongodb\lib\operations\execute_operation.js:59:17)
at callbackWithRetry (C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\API JUGADORES\node_modules\mongodb\lib\operations\execute_operation.js:131:14)
at executeCommand (C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\API JUGADORES\node_modules\mongodb\lib\operations\estimated_document_count.js:47:7)
at server.command (C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\API JUGADORES\node_modules\mongodb\lib\operations\command_v2.js:96:7)
at wireProtocol.command (C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\API JUGADORES\node_modules\mongodb\lib\core\sdam\server.js:253:7)
at C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\API JUGADORES\node_modules\mongodb\lib\core\connection\pool.js:420:18
at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:61:11)
```

does anyone know why this happens?

Thanks

Comment: You are throwing an exception if the count is greater than 5. If this is your intended behavior, then you'll need to catch the exception and handle it as needed.

Comment: thanks for response michael. Yes, >5 is the idea. how can i catch the exception?

Comment: Wrap it with a try/catch

Answer (score 0):

You are throwing an exception if `count` is greater than 5. This might not be necessary as you could simply return a truthy statement like this:

As a Promise to await the callback:

```
new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    playerModel.count({ idteam: player.idteam }, function (err, count) {
        return resolve(count > 5);
    });
})
.then(hasMoreThanFive => {
   if (hasMoreThanFive === true) {
       //has more than 5
   }
   else {
       //does not have more than 5
   }
});
```

Or just using the callback itself:

```
playerModel.count({ idteam: player.idteam }, function (err, count) {
    if (count > 5){
        //place code if has more than 5 here
    }
    else {
        //place code if does not have more than 5 here
    }
});
```

If you absolutely insist on having this throw an exception if there are more than 5, then you would catch it like this:

```
new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    playerModel.count({ idteam: player.idteam }, function (err, count) {
        if (count > 5){
            return reject('Equipo completo');
        }
        return resolve(true);
    });
})
.then(() => {
   //does not have more than 5
})
.catch(() => {
    //has more than 5
});
```